# Problem with moving opencart website to new domain/server

Tags: php, database, opencart, e-commerce

Hi i moved my opencart website to new domain and theres huge problem i cant seem to figure out, i cant see any images, and i cant see translations on a lot of text.

Website is using template.

I did all the steps correctly:

1. export database
2. import to new database
3. changed configuration in config.php and admin/confing.php to new database
4. uploaded files to new server

Site is running on new domain but i cant see any images, and i cant see translations on a lot of text.

**This is new domain:** https://ecogreenbags.eu/

**This is old one so you can see how it should look like:** https://green-bags.sk/

Database is obviously running because all products are there, i can enter admininstration, all orders are there and everything, just not images and that text. I doublechecked if there is uploaded the language folders with that translations, everything is there, FTP is EXACT CLONE of old one except changed config.php files

I have no idea where is the problem. Any ideas ? Thanks a lot

Comment: It looks like the path to your translation and images files is incorrect. Maybe you made a typo or uppercase/lowercase problem. Check if the images are statically available when accessed directly. Edit: Actually I checked and they are. Maybe it is a hardcoded domain name?

Comment: Hi, i checked and statically they are there, for example the blue background in quotes div is here: https://ecogreenbags.eu/image/cache/catalog/bg-t-2050x640.jpg but not showing on website.

Comment: What do you mean hardcoded domain name ? I was the one that made the website, its just opencart 2.3xx with template that i modified. I just check for mentions of old domain name in code (green-bags.sk) and there are none, so no hardcoded, also weird thing is that when i inspect the quote div, there is not background-image property on the element like on old website, element is class="rd-parallax-layer" I have no idea how that can happen because the content is exact clone as well as database

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Double check your config.php files both in root of site and folder admin. Its most likely to be a typo in the config.php in the absolute path to images.

May also be worth checking the file permissions\ownership of the image folder\files.

Comment: I see this has been marked as the accepted solution - it would be good for the question asker to comment with what the problem actually was.

Answer (score 2):

Please confirm to recheck following two variable value is correct in both config file.
\config.php and \admin\config.php

```
define('DIR_IMAGE', '/home/example/public_html/opencart/image/');
define('DIR_LANGUAGE', '/home/example/public_html/opencart/catalog/language/');
```

you may double check your correct document root path in server.
Get correct doucment root path by echo following in config file.

```
echo $_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"];
```

Comment: You were right there was a typo in both, i feel so dumb now, thanks a lot, fixed

Comment: @Martin Sprušanský, Thanks.